# index.html NOT loading style.css on mobile browser (offline, saved in folder)

Tags: android, html, css, mobile-browser

(**Please read before bad feedback. There are similar questions but not what im looking for.**)

I have a web page, made on a Desktop PC saved in a **folder**. (Not using any XAMPP or anything else, just the Live Server plugin inside Visual Studio Code.)

I have copy/paste the folder from my Desktop to my phone (Huawei P10).
Than i simply open "index.html" but the only thing loads is the content created....no images, no style, no nothing. Any help on this please?

Of course i have my "style.css" in a folder named "css", and images in a folder named "img".

See images also:

I'm using Chrome on mobile.

Html Head code:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>iPhone8 product presentation | Welcome</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
```

[image: my main folder]

[image: my css folder]

[image: my image folder]

Comment: do you have any live website, or can you please show me how did you call style.css

Comment: Directory names were case sensitive. do you have it in css folder CSS folder?

Comment: @Viira , i should have images and style all together in only one common folder? This is how you can view an offline site on mobile, inside a folder ?

Comment: @Vetri , i dont have a LIVE website. And i called my css style (style.css).

Comment: @Vetri we've met before already in post lol. :D

Comment: @attila.hajdo if you are using the same folder then just set the path as href="style.css"

Comment: @Viira , i have addes some screenshots also for you to see

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177721/discussion-between-viira-and-attila-hajdo).

Comment: your way of calling is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The way you are calling it is correct. I have checked your gdrive link for the code repository , ran the index.html on my tab. It is working fine for me. I don't think your code has any issue.

Debug it to figure out the issue. Try Remote Debugging on Chrome.

To debug this you can simply:

> 1. Open the Developer Options on your Android.
> 2. Select Enable USB Debugging.
> 3. On your development machine, open Chrome.
> 4. Open DevTools.(ctrl+shift+i)
> 5. In DevTools, click the Main Menu (click in vertical ellipsis icon on the top right) then select More tools > Remote devices.
> 6. In DevTools - Remote devices, open the Settings tab.
> 7. Make sure that the Discover USB devices checkbox is enabled.
> 8. Connect your Android device directly to your development machine using a USB cable. The first time you do this, you usually see that
>      DevTools has detected an unknown device. If you see a green dot and
>      the text Connected below the model name of your Android device, then
>      DevTools has successfully established the connection to your device.
> 9. If your device is showing up as Unknown, accept the Allow USB Debugging permission prompt on your Android device.
> 10. Then you can check console tab to see if there are some errors or not.